# Calculate the functions $e^{kd/dt}f(t)$ and $e^{td/dt}f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

The problem reads as follows:

A slight generalization of the Taylor expansion is

$$f(x+a)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{a^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x)=f(x+a)$$

Calculate the functions $e^{kd/dt}f(t)$ and $e^{td/dt}f(t)$

The answer in each case is a simple, analytic function, not a series.

Im confused as to why he would provide the Taylor series expansion but we will not use it for our answer?

Comment: What is $d/dt $

Comment: The Taylor series for the exponential of the operator 
$$e^{k\frac{d}{dt}}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\Big(k\frac{d}{dt}\Big)^{m}$$
So
$$e^{k\frac{d}{dt}}f(t)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\Big(k\frac{d}{dt}\Big)^{m}f(t)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{k^{m}}{m!}\frac{d^{m}}{dt^{m}}f(t)=f(t+k)$$
and
$$e^{t\frac{d}{dt}}f(t)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\Big(t\frac{d}{dt}\Big)^{m}f(t)$$
I know that
$$\Big(t\frac{d}{dt}\Big)^{m}f(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{m}C_{n}^{m}t^{n}\frac{d^{n}f(t)}{dx^{n}}$$
Where $C_{n}^{m}$ is a binomial coefficient. But it is not clear to me how to proceed further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've managed the first one in the comments, so I'll look at the second one. We have two ways in: we can either write $e^{td/dt}$ as a series and apply it to $f(t)$, or expand $f(t)$ as a series $\sum_{k} f^{(k)}(0)t^k/k!$ and act on the individual terms. Let's try the latter. We need to know
$$ e^{td/dt} t^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\left( t \frac{d}{dt} \right)^n t^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{n!} t^k $$
since $t\frac{d}{dt}t^k = kt^k$. Thus
$$ e^{td/dt} t^k = e^k t^k. $$
Ah, but this is $(et)^k$! Thus
$$ e^{td/dt} f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} e^{td/dt} t^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} (et)^k = f(et) $$
(assuming the expansion exists, of course). So while $e^{kd/dt}$ acts as a translation on the argument, $e^{td/dt}$ acts as a scaling: $$ e^{atd/dt} f(t) = f(e^a t). $$